# Secure rest service

Tags: spring, rest, ssl, truststore

I need to create a SSL service using certificates. I have a .jks file from a client and have created truststore. We are using spring in our application. How to enable / secure rest POST service using certificates.

I know how to read and use trust store to consume it, but I am looking for guidance on how to secure the service.

Answer (score 0):

You have SSL certificate which will be used to authenticate and authorize your server request by application server and not by the REST API.Your application settings at server should have setting to **allow only https requests and deny all http requests.**

For securing REST API you can choose below mentioned way.

1)Basic Authetication

2) OAuth1 Mechanism

3) OAuth2

4) JWT Token

Comment: The problem is far bigger than that. Just using TLS is not enough, without precautions. Have a look at this eye-opening study: https://www.cs.utexas.edu/~shmat/shmat_ccs12.pdf

Comment: I already have a certificate at the server side which i cannot use for this service. so this has to be custom verification for one service. I have multiple controller exposing different end point which I dont want to secure. we need only one controller to be secured and using that certificate for verification that it is a valid client.